# Getting button to fire using Controller as vm syntax in AngularJS 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got the code below that shows that I can use $scope.interestToggle = syntax but not vm.interestToggle = syntax to assign a listener to a button click.  I'm trying to avoid using $scope.  Is there a correct or better way to put a listener in a controller than hanging it off $scope?

```
(function () {
 "use strict";
  angular
    .module("svCodeCamp")
    .controller( "SessionListCtrl",
                ['$scope',"sessionResource",
                    SessionListCtrl]);

 function SessionListCtrl($scope,sessionResource) {

    var vm = this;

    // WORKS
    $scope.interestToggle = function(item) {
        debugger;
    }

    // DOES NOT WORK
    vm.interestToggle = function(item) {
        debugger;
    }

    //<td>
    //<button ng:click="interestToggle()">Add</button>
    //</td>
```

Comment: have you set `ng-controller="SessionListCtrl as list"` and tried a `<button ng-click="list.interestToggle()">Add</button>`?

Comment: when I do what you asuggest zwacky I get the error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SessionListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 0):

Global controllers aren't *(completely)* supported in 1.3.

you should be using:

```
angular.module("svCodeCamp").controller("SessionListCtrl", ['$scope',"sessionResource", function() {
    // controller content
]);
```

or use this to reenable global controllers:

```
angular.module('svCodeCamp').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Comment: zwacky, I'm not following how your first option is any different than what I have.  Also, do I still need to use $scope.interestToggle?  I'm trying to avoid using $scope if possible.

Comment: You're using `SessionListCtrl` as a global function. That means you're *polluting* the global name space. And that specific pollution is not allowed in angular 1.3 anymore.

Comment: zwacky Is there a way to pull the function out of the parameter list so it is not inline (and not pollute the global name space)?  Thanks for the answer. that makes sense to me.

Comment: Best practice is having one controller/service/directive/... per file, starting like my first code block in my answer (`angular.module("svCodeCamp").controller/directive/factory/...`). This way you register your controller into the angular container, without having references outside in the global name space.

Comment: zwacky one more question. I'm seeing the pattern with the function in a Pluralsight AngularJS course inside an IIFE.  I assume that solves the problem of polluting global name space. true?  Is that still not allowed in 1.3 (assuming it does not pollute global)